# ALOS Satellite Product to PNG conversion issue (missing rotation)

Tags: java, geocoding, image-rotation, satellite-image, beam

I'm trying to export a PNG quicklook of an ALOS AVNIR-2 product using the [BEAM](http://www.brockmann-consult.de/cms/web/beam/forum) java APIs. The following picture shows the RGB preview of the prduct, as it appears in the GUI of beam.

[image: ALOS Satellite product quicklook, rotated according to its geocoding information.]

As you can see, the image is not upright, due to its geocoding. I've developed a very simple java program to export the quicklook of the product.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] rgbBandNames = new String[3];
    rgbBandNames[0] = "radiance_3";
    rgbBandNames[1] = "radiance_2";
    rgbBandNames[2] = "radiance_1";

    try {
    //Product inputProduct = ProductIO.readProduct(args[0]);
        Product inputProduct = ProductIO.readProduct("C:\\nfsdata\\VOL-ALAV2A152763430-O1B2R_U");

        Band[] produtBands = inputProduct.getBands();
        Band[] rgbBands = new Band[3];

        int n = 0;
        for (Band band : produtBands) {
            if (band.getName().equals(rgbBandNames[0])) {
                rgbBands[0] = band;
            } else if (band.getName().equals(rgbBandNames[1])) {
                rgbBands[1] = band;
            } else if (band.getName().equals(rgbBandNames[2])) {
                rgbBands[2] = band;
            }

            n = n + 1;
        }

        ImageInfo outImageInfo = ProductUtils.createImageInfo(rgbBands, true, ProgressMonitor.NULL);
        BufferedImage outImage = ProductUtils.createRgbImage(rgbBands, outImageInfo, ProgressMonitor.NULL);

        ImageIO.write(outImage, "PNG", new File(inputProduct.getName() + ".png"));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The program works, but every PNG image i get from it is an upright PNG image, like the following.

[image: ALOS Satellite product quicklook, upright.]

Now, I know that it is not possible to have geocoding information inside a PNG image. I need only to reproduce the same "rotation" of the image.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. In other words, I managed to **extract the quicklook from an ALOS AV2 O1B2R_U product, rotated according to the geocoding information of the product** (see the image below).

[image: ALOS Satellite product quicklook, rotated according to its geocoding information.]

The reason for this is that the ALOS AV2 O1B2R_U products have the geocoding rotation **already applied to the raster**. As a consequence, in order to successfulyl export a quicklook, the rotation must be retrieved from the native raster and applied to the output image.
For future reference, I'd like to recap and share my solution with the community. This is my main class:

```
import com.bc.ceres.core.ProgressMonitor;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.esa.beam.framework.dataio.ProductIO;
import org.esa.beam.framework.datamodel.Band;
import org.esa.beam.framework.datamodel.ImageInfo;
import org.esa.beam.framework.datamodel.MapGeoCoding;
import org.esa.beam.framework.datamodel.Product;
import org.esa.beam.util.ProductUtils;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String inputProductPath = "path\to\input\product";
    String outputProductPath = "path\to\output\image";

    // Read the source product.
    Product inputProduct = ProductIO.readProduct(inputProductPath);

    // Extract the RGB bands.
    String[] bandNames = new String[3];
    Band[] bandData = new Band[3];

    bandNames[0] = "radiance_3";
    bandNames[1] = "radiance_2";
    bandNames[2] = "radiance_1";

    for (Band band : inputProduct.getBands()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < bandNames.length; i++) {

            if (band.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(bandNames[ i ])) {
                bandData[ i ] = band;
            }
        }
    }

    // Generate quicklook image.
    ImageInfo outImageInfo = ProductUtils.createImageInfo(bandData, true, ProgressMonitor.NULL);
    BufferedImage outImage = ProductUtils.createRgbImage(bandData, outImageInfo, ProgressMonitor.NULL);
    outImage = resize(outImage, WIDTH, 1200);

    // Extract the orientation.
    double orientation;
    if (inputProduct.getGeoCoding() != null) {
        orientation = -((MapGeoCoding) inputProduct.getGeoCoding()).getMapInfo().getOrientation();
    } else {
        orientation = 0.0;
    }
    outImage = rotate(outImage, orientation);

    // Write image.
    ImageIO.write(outImage, "PNG", new File(outputProductPath));
}
```

Once the rotation angle of the quicklook has been extracted from the source product (see the above code), it must be applied to the output image (BufferedImage). In the above code, two simple image manipulation functions are employed: resize(...) and rotate(...), see below for their definition.

```
    /**
 * Resizes the image {@code tgtImage} by setting one of its dimensions
 * (width or height, specified via {@code tgtDimension}) to {@code tgtSize}
 * and dynamically calculating the other one in order to preserve the aspect
 * ratio.
 *
 * @param tgtImage The image to be resized.
 * @param tgtDimension The selected dimension: {@code ImageUtil.WIDTH} or
 * {@code ImageUtil.WIDTH}.
 * @param tgtSize The new value for the selected dimension.
 *
 * @return The resized image.
 */
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage tgtImage, short tgtDimension, int tgtSize) {

    int newWidth = 0, newHeight = 0;

    if (HEIGHT == tgtDimension) {
        newHeight = tgtSize;
        newWidth = (tgtImage.getWidth() * tgtSize) / tgtImage.getHeight();
    } else {
        newHeight = (tgtImage.getHeight() * tgtSize) / tgtImage.getWidth();
        newWidth = tgtSize;
    }

    Image tmp = tgtImage.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGemoticon;

    Graphics2D g2d = outImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    return outImage;
}

/**
 * Rotates the image {@code tgtImage} by {@code tgtAngle} degrees clockwise.
 *
 * @param tgtImage The image to be rotated.
 * @param tgtAngle The rotation angle (expressed in degrees).
 *
 * @return The resized image.
 */
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage tgtImage, double tgtAngle) {

    int w = tgtImage.getWidth();
    int h = tgtImage.getHeight();

    AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
    t.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(tgtAngle), w / 2d, h / 2d);

    Point[] points = {
        new Point(0, 0),
        new Point(w, 0),
        new Point(w, h),
        new Point(0, h)
    };

    // Transform to destination rectangle.
    t.transform(points, 0, points, 0, 4);

    // Get destination rectangle bounding box
    Point min = new Point(points[0]);
    Point max = new Point(points[0]);
    for (int i = 1, n = points.length; i < n; i++) {
        Point p = points[ i ];
        double pX = p.getX(), pY = p.getY();

        // Update min/max x
        if (pX < min.getX()) {
            min.setLocation(pX, min.getY());
        }
        if (pX > max.getX()) {
            max.setLocation(pX, max.getY());
        }

        // Update min/max y
        if (pY < min.getY()) {
            min.setLocation(min.getX(), pY);
        }
        if (pY > max.getY()) {
            max.setLocation(max.getX(), pY);
        }
    }

    // Determine new width, height
    w = (int) (max.getX() - min.getX());
    h = (int) (max.getY() - min.getY());

    // Determine required translation
    double tx = min.getX();
    double ty = min.getY();

    // Append required translation
    AffineTransform translation = new AffineTransform();
    translation.translate(-tx, -ty);
    t.preConcatenate(translation);

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(t, null);
    BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGemoticon;
    op.filter(tgtImage, outImage);

    return outImage;
}
```